# Loop through SqlDataSource result if underlying SP returns more than one Table

Tags: .net, sql

I have Asp.net application with SqlDataSource ojbect that calls t-sql sctored procedure. It returns more than one table (it returns aboout 20 different tables in format:

```
1.table -> event1 data
2.table -> event2 participation data

3.table -> event2 data
4.table ->event2 participation data
etc.
```

Everything works fine. However, I do not understand how to get all those tables from SqlDataSource result. I do not need any GridView or Repeater. I need to manually loop through SqlDataSource results. I do not know how.

When I was searching on how to convert SqlDataSource to DataSet, it suggests SqlDataSource.Select -> get DataView -> convert toTable, but this works only for one table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DataSet ds;
myAdap.Fill(ds);
if(ds.tables.count >0){
if(ds.tablles[0]..rows.cout >0){
  foreach(datarow dr in ds.tables[0].rows){  //do someting with table 1}
}
if(ds.tables[1].rows.count>0){
  foreach(datarow dr in ds.tables[1].rows){  //do seomthing with table 2}
}
}
ds.dispose();


<asp:SqlDataSource  
     ID="SqlDataSource1"  
     runat="server"  
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>"  
     DataSourceMode="DataSet"  
     SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 25 ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice FROM Products"  
     >  
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I do not have myAdap. I have SqlDataSource. There is no Fill method or similar. If I have data in DataSet then I now how to loop. I do not know how to get those data.